# Problems converting wide string to multibyte in c++

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, string-conversion

I'm trying to convert a path from a wstring to a string. But when I do it outputs garbage. Is there a way to get these japanese characters into a string?

```
wstring foo = L"C:\\projects\\サービス\\b2";
char bar[256] = { 0 };
string baz( bar );

int len = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, foo.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0 );
WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, foo.c_str(), -1, &bar[0], len, 0, 0 );
```

when debugging on windows (vs2019) baz contains: "C:\projects\ã‚µãƒ¼ãƒ“ã‚¹\b2"

[image: debugging view]

Comment: When debugging the display is probably not UTF-8 - you will need to check the hex representation of the string to check it's encoding.  Windows is natively UTF-16LE or code pages, UTF-8 support is not universal in the tools.

Comment: @RichardCritten yeah, I have unfortunately, its indeed giberish. foo displays fine, just not bar/baz.

Comment: It looks like its turning wide chars into multiple characters instead of multi-byte chars. Or maybe I misunderstand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Your code is working fine. It's the debugger that displays gibberish because it has no plan that `bar` is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: BTW: There is a problem in your code. You need to initialize `baz` after the UTF-8 conversion as the `baz` constructor copies the content of `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Codo explained it was actually the correct data. And as @Richard Critten tried to explain, I needed to check the hex, not just the decimals.

For others encountering similar problems I wanted to do this so that later I could test the string to see if the directory exists. Here's how I did that:

Since I was using stat, it didn't like the "unicode" string. So I had to convert back to a wstring using MultiByteToWideChar and use the wide string version: _wstat.

So assuming path is actually wchars:

```
int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, path, -1, NULL, 0 );
wchar_t *wpath = new wchar_t[wchars_num];
MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, path, -1, wpath, wchars_num );

struct _stat64i32 wInfo;
statRC = _wstat( wpath, &wInfo );
if ( statRC != 0 )
{
    if ( errno == ENOENT ) { return false; } // something along the path does not exist
    if ( errno == ENOTDIR ) { return false; } // something in path prefix is not a dir
    return false;
}
else if ( wInfo.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting properly, but not viewing the string correctly in the debugger.  The default when viewing the `char*` in Visual Studio is to assume an ANSI encoding specific to the localized version of Windows used.  In Western European/US Windows, that would be Windows-1252.

At least as of Visual Studio 2015, use the `s8` format code in the Watch Window to view UTF-8-encoded strings:

[image: main() with OP code viewing variables with and without s8 format code in watch window]

See [Format specifiers in the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp)

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating any memory for the target `string`. You are creating the `string` from an empty `char[]` first, THEN you are converting into that same `char[]`, which will NOT update the `string` automatically.

You don't need the `char[]` at all. Try this instead:

```cpp
wstring foo = L"C:\\projects\\サービス\\b2";
string baz;

int len = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, foo.c_str(), foo.size(), NULL, 0, 0, 0 );
baz.resize(len);
WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, foo.c_str(), foo.size(), &baz[0]/*or: baz.data()*/, len, 0, 0 );
```